# Using split(":") to get numbers from a string but I keep missing the first number

Tags: python, string

I need to extract 2 numbers from several strings.

This is an example and the code i am using:

```
data = 'Ant Graph first exam is :2 and the score after the second exam is :10'
print ([int (s) for s in data.split(":") if s.isdigit()])
```

output [10]

but if I remove the : and change a bit the code:

```
data = 'Ant Graph first exam is 2 and the score after the second exam is 10'
print ([int (s) for s in data.split(" ") if s.isdigit()])
```

output [2, 10]

Why in the first case do I miss the number 2?

Comment: You're splitting on colons. Does that 2 look like it's surrounded by colons?

Comment: Have you tried printing `data.split(":")` ?

Comment: ... and if that does not help, try to print `data.split(" ")` and compare the results.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I don’t think such a harsh response is needed, the same can be said more politely.

Comment: @Zanzag I read that as a completely value-neutral question.

Comment: I honestly think we have different expertise and if u are a newbie things do not look so easy. Thanks masoj clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the reason the first code doesn't work is because it split you data like this :

```
["Ant Graph first exam is","2 and the score after the second exam is ","10"]
```

So when you try to test `isdigit()` on the second item this cannot return a digit because "2" is inside a larger string. And "10" is by itself.

Hope it's clear and i'm not wrong.